# Running an application with error "The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit

I've checked through various pages of Google and have found no solution as it pertains to my system. This is a 64 bit system and from what I read there is no Jet OLEDB 4.0 for 64 bit systems and if I wanted to fix this I would have to compile and build the application under a different specification. If I don't have the application code is there a way to run this application without the error appearing?

Comment: No. The library your trying to use does not support x64 operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Windows SDK, install it and use the tool [CorFlags.exe to set the 32BIT flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164699%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
CorFlags.exe Program.exe /32BIT+
```

Now the tool runs as 32Bit and should work.

Comment: I'll try this out and see if it works. *fingers crossed*